# ms-vscode.cpptools taking a ton of CPU usage

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm working on Ubuntu and using MS Remote SSH as part of Remote Explorer through VSCode. When I installed C/C++ (ms-vscode.cpptools) extension, it takes up a ton of CPU%, typically around 95. I thought perhaps this is a one time thing, but it's constantly running at that percentage, making everything else (compiling the project) very slow.

I like the functionality of this extension, as I've used it on other machines before without issue. However I can't use it if it's staying at that level of usage. Is there any workaround for this? I've seen a few github debates, but nothing much coming from those.

From system monitor:
[image]

Comment: Same issue here. Maybe you have a build directory that needs to be excluded from the linter? Seems to be the problem in my case. vscode excludes only certain directories like **/build or **/.vscode from indexing

Comment: I got the same issue. I have a large codebase and cpptools take around 15GB of RAM.

Comment: I have `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize": 0,` and `"C_Cpp.default.browse.limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,`. Perhaps you could give those a try, but I think those might have more to do with disk and RAM and of course have implications for intellisense behaviour. Do you have the clang-format code analysis enabled? Can you [edit] to give some more info about the processes which are consuming large amounts of CPU cycles? Which processes, what are their arguments, and how much are they each using (if there are multiple)?

Comment: @rainbow.gekota, Thanks for the suggestion about the limits - This helps much.

Comment: @rainbow.gekota, Have added the cmdline usage of the tool  - see screenshot

Comment: @Nujufas Hold on a minute... The issue you have is not the same. The original question was about CPU usage, and your question is about RAM usage. The right thing would be to check if there is an existing question that your question is _actually_ similar to, and put your bounty on that, or if there isn't, ask a new question. Probably best to ask a new question since it will really depend on your context. Ask a new one and include as much useful/relevant detail as you can.

Answer (score 6):

After trying lots of solutions, only one works for me - adding `files.exclude` in settings file.

When adding `files.exclude`, the following lines will be add by default:

```
"**/.git": true,
"**/.svn": true,
"**/.hg": true,
"**/.deps": true,
"**/CVS": true,
"**/.DS_Store": true,
```

then I add some files/folder, which are in workspace but they have nothing to do with IntelliSense, such as "**/*.Po", folder that stores test data (lots of files...), which are always been updated when I use my application, etc.

and I also add

```
"/bin": true,
"/boot": true,
"/cdrom": true,
"/dev": true,
"/proc": true,
"/etc":true
```

, but I am not sure if those lines help.

After updating the settings file, we should `Restart IntelliSense for Active File` and `Reset IntelliSense Database` by the Command Palette.

btw, after using the above solution, I haven't encountered long-running high CPU usage for over two months.

Comment: a very useful setting: "C_Cpp.workspaceParsingPriority": "medium"